# Are there any open phylogenetic projects that don't require coding to make a contribution

Tags: evolution, phylogenetics, human-evolution, molecular-evolution, protein-evolution

I am stay at home learner, not pursuing education formal education and currently doing a part time job. I've however completed masters in biotechnology and I'm studying to pursue PhD in molecular evolution eventually. I'm interested in knowing if there are any online open projects in phylogenetics and computational molecular evolution where I can contribute. Leave the projects involving coding. So are there such open projects that don't require coding? An example of contribution I can think of right now is submitting new phylogenetic trees. Please help, I can't find any information online.